# Symbol lookup error on Fedora 22 while trying to run Quartus II

Tags: fedora

I've been trying to start Quartus II on my system (which is a DELL running Fedora 22 64-bit). Now I try to run the binary file in command line and I get hit with this weird error as follow:

```
[kuma0629@eecad47 bin]$ ./quartus
quartus: symbol lookup error: /lib/libXext.so.6: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest
```

Now, I googled this problem and seems like libX11 needs to be upgraded. But I'm not sure how to do this for Fedora in particular because there's not much support online.

How do I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: where did you install quartus from? Update using `sudo dnf update`.

Comment: Sorry, I should've given you more background. This has already been installed by my university on the university lab computers. So I'm not sure exactly where they've installed quartus from.

Comment: `quartus` is not in the official repositories so it might get out of sync with libraries shipped in Fedora if it was built a lot earlier. Anyway you can simply update all the system using `sudo dnf update` as I mentioned earlier. It might help.